# Making a dynamic CheckboxGroupInput with shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, checkbox, dynamic, shiny

I am trying to make a checkbox to be able to filter the dataset by years. However not every variable has all the data for every year so I wanted only the years where the variable has data for shown in the ui. Sadly, after splitting my code into conditional panels the buttons do not filter any longer.

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Select2 == 'AFD' | input.Select2 == 'Piraten'",
                           checkboxGroupInput("Year", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                                              choices =  "2013"),
                                              selected = "2013"),
         conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Select2 == 'DieLinke'",
                         checkboxGroupInput("Year", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                                            choices = list("2009", "2013"),
                                            selected = "2013")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Select2 == 'Gruene' | input.Select2 == 'FDP' | input.Select2 == 'SPD' | input.Select2 == 'CDU'",
                         checkboxGroupInput("Year", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                                            choices = list("1998", "2002", "2005","2009", "2013"),
       selected = "2013"))
```

Does anyone know why?

Here's an example of plot being generated in the server function:

```
dfParteien %>%
                                                filter(Partei %in% chosen_party) %>% 
                                                filter(Jahr %in% input$Year) %>%
                                                count(word) %>%
                                                with(wordcloud(word, n, max.words = input$Slider1, colors=pal12))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a working example using `mtcars` dataset which is going to help you achieve dynamic `checkboxGroupInput` and further filtering of data frame:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data <- mtcars

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("select1", "select cyl:", choices = unique(data$cyl)),
    uiOutput("checkbox"),
dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$checkbox <- renderUI({
      choice <-  unique(data[data$cyl %in% input$select1, "gear"])
      checkboxGroupInput("checkbox","Select gear", choices = choice, selected = choice[1])

    })

    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      data <-  data %>% filter(cyl %in% input$select1) %>% filter(gear %in% input$checkbox)
      datatable(data)
    })

   }
)
```

You do not really need to use `conditionalPanel`, it works much better in your case if you just move `checkboxGroupInput` to the server and use `input$select` to filter your choices.

**First of all:**
Your example code is not good, you should learn how to create [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

**Second of all:**
Your code has a quite few mistakes such as giving three `checkboxGroupInput` widgets same ID (Year), which is not going to work, the ID must be unique for each widget in shiny.